# Сравнение 2х массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы, property

Всем привет,
Имеется задача сравнить 2 массива и вывести результат с отсутствующим ID/.

> Изначально 2 массива имели одинаковые значения.
>
> После во 2 массиве удалили объект с id 2 ("Приложение 3").
>
> После сравнения 1 массива и 2 массива получаем ID удалённого объекта, т.е 2

1 массив

```
[{"id":3,"title":"Приложение 1","idapp":1},{"id":1,"title":"Приложение 2","idapp":2},{"id":2,"title":"Приложение 3","idapp":3}]
```

2 массив

```
[{"id":3,"title":"Приложение 1","idapp":1},{"id":1,"title":"Приложение 2","idapp":2}]
```

как удалить объект с id2 в 1 массиве?

Comment: А вопрос в чём? То есть с чем именно у вас возникла проблема, когда вы начали решать задачу?

Comment: не могу получить нужный результат, т.е удаленный элемент массива (его ID)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вопрос решён своими силами и неожиданно.

```
var result1 = [{"id":3,"title":"Приложение 1","idapp":1},{"id":1,"title":"Приложение 2","idapp":2},{"id":2,"title":"Приложение 3","idapp":3}];

var result2 = [{"id":3,"title":"Приложение 1","idapp":1},{"id":1,"title":"Приложение 2","idapp":2}];

var props = ['id', 'title'];

var result = result1.filter(function(o1){
    // filter out (!) items in result2
    return !result2.some(function(o2){
        return o1.id === o2.id;          // assumes unique id
    });
}).map(function(o){
    // use reduce to make objects with only the required properties
    // and map to apply this to the filtered array as a whole
    return props.reduce(function(newo, name){
        newo[name] = o[name];
        return newo;
    }, {});
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 4) +
        '</pre>';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7y4mc7kq/